# Unable to transform a date to string beanshell

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell

I'm new to JMeter, I need to send a report multiple time with minimal differences, and one of the parameters is system date, the format i need is :

dd-MMM-yyyy

sample code:

```
String result = ${__time(d-MMM-yyyy)};
log.info(result);
```

I also tried

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

Date date = ${__time(d-MMM-yyyy)};
String result = formatTo.format(date);
log.info(result);
```

none of which worked, also is there any way to debug in beanshell Jmeter because the exception thrown basically returns all the lines not the specific stack that caused the issue

Comment: is the exception confidential? or you think it's gonna hurt our feelings if you show it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get date formatted with one liner using [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
log.info(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yyyy").format(new Date()));
```